# Is there a method in Excel VBA for on lost cell focus?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet, the goal is to run several macros after user input is compleete.  I was looking for a lost focus method to run when the user exits a specific cell.

I did find a way to make this work but it surprised me that I wasnt able to find something a little more straight forward.  I am curious if there is a better way to acomplish this.

On sheet "MyWorksheet", I have a named range, its a individual cell for user input, "myNamedRange", the macro should execute when the user exits this cell. My current version uses the Worksheet_SelectionChange event to achive the desired result.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal location As Range)

    Static target As Range
    Set target = Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("myNamedRange")
    
    Static found As Boolean
   
    If found = True And location.Address <> target.Address Then

        ' Do stuff here
        
    End If

    If location.Address = target.Address Then
        found = True
    Else
        found = False
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I might be missing something obvious, curious to know if there is a better way to acomplish this.

Comment: the closest is worksheet_change event, which fires if the cell is changed after edit mode.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/worksheet-object-events) is all the worksheet events